# PHP get image file type

Tags: php

- **$_FILES['file']['type']**
      `$imageType = $_FILES['file']['type'];`
- **getimageSize()**
      `$info = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);`
      `$mime = $info['mime'];`
- **exif_imagetype()**
      `$imageType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);`

My question is which one should I use in order to get the image file type?

Comment: `$_FILES['file']['type']`

Comment: @Aldi Exactly wrong.

Comment: Which one is work for you? Than use that! Don't be complicate yourself.

Comment: @deceze what is the right one?

Comment: @Aldi See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_FILES` merely contains the value that the browser/client specified the uploaded file to be. It is an arbitrary, user supplied value. Don't use it for anything except debugging.

`getimagesize()` is a function of the gd library and is maintained there. It happens to also do image type detection. The gd library is generally decent enough, but you need to have it installed.

`exif_imagetype()` is a function of the PHP exif extension, which does exclusively image type detection. The exif extension needs to be enabled if you want to use this function. It's also decent enough.

Choose either of the latter two, whichever seems more robust to you, offers the better features or is installed on all your systems. It's hard to give a recommendation for one or the other, in my experience they both work fine.